# If $f$ is defined on $R$ and $f(K)$ is compact whenever $K$ is compact, then is $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$?

Tags: continuity, compactness

If $f$ is defined on $R$ and $f(K)$ is compact whenever $K$ is compact, then is $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$?

I know that if $f : K → R$ is continuous and $K \in R$ is compact, then $f(K)$ is compact, but does is the converse of this true?

Or in other words does compactness of $f(K)$ imply continuity?

Comment: Suppose that f maps rational numbers to 0 and irrational ones to 1.

Comment: More generally, consider any function with finite image.

Comment: I was going to suggest the floor function. It would map compact intervals to a finite subset of the integers (i.e., a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$),  but is definitely not continuous.